# Как решить ошибку #1242 - Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи в MYSQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

мне необходимо каждому пользователю у которого dolg > 0 добавить запись о списании процентов в таблицу transactions, но мне выдает ошибку #1242 - Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи. Что делать?

```
INSERT INTO `transactions`(`id`, `number_tr`, `owner`, `card`, `card_type`, `merchant`, `cotegory`, `date`, `time`, `summ`, `hash`, `color`, `icon`, `comiss`, `rekviz`, `msg`, `summstart`, `currency`, `exc`) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM `credit_cards` WHERE dolg > 0),
(SELECT RAND()),
'',
(SELECT last FROM credit_cards WHERE dolg > 0),
'credit',
'Списание процентов по кредиту',
'Другое',
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%m.%y')),
'00:00:00',
(SELECT -(dolg / 100 * 3.825) FROM credit_cards WHERE dolg > 0),
(SELECT RAND()),
'bg-secondary',
'fas fa-percentage',
'0',
(SELECT bill FROM credit_cards WHERE dolg > 0),
'',
(SELECT (dolg / 100 * 3.825) FROM credit_cards WHERE dolg > 0),
'',
'')
```

Comment: Потому что, а какое поведение вы ожидали? Ошибка сама обьясняет себя

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно каждому пользователю добавить(индивидуальную) запись в таблицу transactions с определенными данными, которые берутся из другой таблицы. Как можно сделать одним запросом все эти записи для всех пользователей?

Comment: Выбирать отдельными селектами значения для каждого поля это конечно поразительное решение) На вашем месте, я бы выбрал одним селектом все нужные поля сразу

Comment: `insert into transactions (…) select … from credit_cards where dolg > 0;`

Comment: Выбирайте селектом нужные поля и они вставятся в соотвествии с порядком полей, перечисленных в инсерте

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!!